# Нужна переменная text, которую можно менять из самого скрипта (c#)

Tags: c#, unity3d

Вопрос не очень сложный, но он звучит так - "Как сделать public переменную Text, которую можно изменять в скрипте?" 
Пробовал сделать это так "public Text text;", но там надо было вставлять GameObject text, а мне надо изменить из самого скрипта

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо! Я понял как это делается. Нужен не Text, а String.